# LTSpice PWL issue with Trigger

Tags: ltspice

Perhaps someone can help me. I have a problem with the trigger function in LTSpice.

I load a PWL file and add the following Syntax behind it: 
PWL (File.xx) Trigger V(n001)>1

LTSpice gave me an error saying `Unknown parameter "trigger"`.

Does anyone know why the trigger is not working?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You use an incorrect syntax.

The correct syntax is : "PWL file=FILENAME.txt Trigger V(n001)>1"

Comment: It's true the manual doesn't specify it like this, but it works like this, nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the trigger functionality is not available for current sources.

I've tried it with a voltage source, where it worked like expected.

Exchanging it with a current source and I ended up with the same error message as you. I don't know your PWL file, but maybe it is possible to model the behavior with a B source.

Comment: Thnaks for your quick response. I use repeat for X now and simply changed my PWL in order to fit it for my needs. Works for me now.

Comment: @user229675 This is the answer to your question, and it's the right answer. You should at least check it, so that others, in the future, having similar problems, can find this answer.